I want to export all activity data from my contacts
I am working for an organisation that has stored every communication activity – email, letter, phone call – with each contact in the activity tab, and we need to save it externally. Ideally in a CSV format. Is there any way of doing that?
I am not a coder and am very new to CiviCRM and to Drupal. Can I do this myself or do I need to bring in a coder?
Many thanks,
Andrew

You should be able to do this yourself but perhaps in more goes, depending on the number of activities.
If you select activities from the Search menu SearchKit you should get the option to export the results to CSV in the actions menu?
For example I selected Search Activities from the Search menu, entered some activity types and a date range and pressed Search. In the actions menu when I get the result I have the Export activities option.

This is correct, but a couple of notes:

Use "Export Activities" and not "Download Spreadsheet" - the latter only works for a few thousand records at a time.
This will NOT export attachments - but if you want a CSV format, then you either don't have any, or have already accepted that as a limitation of the format.

